YA sci-fi trilogy where the futuristic space world has an android model for every letter of the alphabet
I read this book series (trilogy??) in high school, about 5 years ago. The cover was maybe pretty monochrome, with silhouettes of the main characters faces opposite each other.
From what I remember, the world had an android model for every letter of the alphabet. The female lead was from a planet that didn't want to be overrun by refugees from Earth, so they were trying to close some portal or other.
On this mission, the female lead ends up in a wrecked spaceship where the android lead has been trapped for 30 years. She ends up using him to help on her mission, but, of course, begins to realise that he's not just an android; that he has a soul or something, somehow.
They run across the android's maker, who wants to upload his consciousness into the android (that was the reason he made the android, with his DNA - when that one was lost in space he tried making others, but he was too old and his DNA didn't work as well anymore).
Across the subsequent books, I think the two lead characters also have a bit of a romance.
